# How to make form_alter act upon boolean choice rather select list

Tags: 8, forms

I am working on a form_alter() based on Form API **states** which is about switching a field choice based on the value of a select field as below;

```
'select[name="field_date_type"]' => ['value' => 'allday']
```

I would like to know what syntax is required for changing the field widget from **select** to boolean or checkboxes or radios.

I have tried switching **select** to *boolean*, *checkbox* and *radio* but none are working for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean *checkbox* (HTML doesn't have a *boolean* input type), the property is `checked`, so you can use:

```
':input[name="field_date_type"]' => ['checked' => TRUE]
```

Comment: Hmm. This isn't working for me. Obs missing something. https://pastebin.com/rH7xuMBq

Comment: The only thing I can spot that might be wrong in that pastebin is that you're wrapping `TRUE` with quotes. Try it without, because other than that it looks like it should work. Core uses the same pattern in dozens of places, and it's even used as the example in the comments for `drupal_process_states()`: `':input[name="remote_checkbox"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)`.